# mean.io stack angular long running operations with http request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, http, mean-stack

I am using the **mean stack** do develop a web application that performs several operations over several mongo db collections.

The systems overal intention is to perform data sinchronization between several systems. Each system data is stored in a different collections. Needless to say that these collection's documents have properties in common.

At the **nodeJS**, or the API level, I created get and post requests that will loop over the main collection asynchronouslye and will try to link documents on that collection with documents in other collections. Naturally this process takes for several minutes.

The documents that were possible to link are stored in a different mongodb collection. These will be later processed in another node js API call.

After the API is set I am creating a controller and a service with angular in order to connect to the api and perform the api get and post requests.

When I get to this point in the UI where I click in a button to perform this link operation, the operation starts without blocking the browser but eventually the browser get an **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** because the operation is still undergoing so I never actually call the `response.end()`.

What I thought could be a possible solution:

1. reply back as soon as the operation starts: PROBLEM -> I need to make sure this operation finishes in order to make other calls on the resulting collection. So I did this operation to finishs to allow others to be done on the resulting data set.

What can I do in order to avoid the browser to close the connection before the long running operation in the background is completed?

**Code:**

**html**-> Button which the user clicks to start linking records:

```
<div>
    <md-button aria-label="link all records" ng-click="vm.linkRecords()">
        <md-icon class="mdi mdi-plus"></md-icon>Link Records
    </md-button>
</div>
```

**controller**: the canLink, canGrade are all boolean variables so that When the server is undergoing one operation none of the others can be performed. Once the operation finishes, it returns true and all operations are allowed.

```
function linkRecords() {
    $state.go('app.records.link');
}// END linkRecords page

$scope.$on('linkRecords', function(event, batchSize){
    if ( canLink && canGrade) {
        showToast("Started linking records");
        canLink  = 0;
        canGrade = 0;
        recordService.linkRecords(batchSize).then(function(finished){
            canLink     = finished;
            canGrade    = finished;
        });
    }else if ( !canLink ){
        showToast('Cannot link records: - Currently undergoing grading records');
    }else if ( !canGrade ){
        showToast('Cannot link records: - Currently undergoing linking records');
    }
});//END linkingRecords
```

**Service**

```
function linkRecords(batchSize){
    return $http.get(urlRoot+'/link/:'+batchSize);
}//END linkRecords
```

**Node js api:**

routes.js:

```
//link all records
app.post('/link/:batchSize', function(req, res){
    var batchSize = req.params.batchSize;
    functions.linkRecords(batchSize, function(callback){
        res.end(true);
    });
});//END linkRecords
```

functions.js:

```
linkRecords : function(batchSize, callback){
    //link all records in all collections a batchsize at a time
    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            ...open cursor for collection1 and loops over the collections to stitch with other collections.
        },
        function(callback){
            ...open cursor for collection2 and loops over the collections to stitch with other collections.
        }
    ], function done(err, result){
        callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you consider use WebSockets/Socket.IO?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a more robust backend infrastructure to manage, and keep track of these long running tasks. if you know these operations are going to be taking a "long time", which could be seconds, to minutes, or longer, then you must set up some type of queue service to run these tasks, track them, and handle error conditions.

The sole responsibility of API server should be to:

1. Receive the User request
2. Validate data in request, return immediate error if invaid
3. If valid, insert new job into a queue that is used to start the processing
4. The API response then returns a "Processing message" to the user, possibly with some ID they can use to track process in a separate API request.

A possible set of APIs that could be implemented for this process:

```
POST /api/links - create a new link process
GET /api/links - display all currently running link processes
GET /api/links/:id - display a single link process
DELETE /api/links/:id - delete (or cancel) a running link process, if needed
```

There are several different queue technologies you can use to manage your long running task. If you are in an AWS environment, you can use [SQS queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-how-it-works.html).  If there are several steps involved in your process, you can look at a system that handles data (or process) pipelines. [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) (open sourced from spotify) is one example service that can be used to handle pipelines that are very simple (ie. one step) up to extremely complicated pipelines with lots of steps and dependencies.

[Here is a tutorial](http://techblog.spanning.com/2015/10/12/Long-running-Node-processes/) that breaks down the issue with long running processes, and then discusses some possible implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on MEAN stack (yet) but I guess the way you design your service is not right. It will return a promise (result is not completed) and you call ends before the promise finish.

try to design your service and route.js call something like this.

**service**

```
angular.module('rugCoPro').factory('appraisalSearch', ['$resource', 'RugSession', function($resource, RugSession) {

        return $resource("/:org/api/models/appraisals/:func/:value", { org: "@org", func: "@func", value: "@value" }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': authToken }
            }
        });


}])
```

**call**

```
   appraisalSearch(RugSession.getAuthToken()).query({ org: org, func: "multi", value: orderNumber[0] }).$promise.then(function(data) {
       //success    
    }, function(error) {
       //error
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would piggy back on Mikelax's answer of using a queue system in order to manage. I have been using [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) to handle longer processes in the project I've been working on.

I think it's worth mentioning (possibly the root of your **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** error) that Express has a default timeout of 2 minutes. So if you have processes that take several minutes, you should modify your timeout on the endpoint to handle the requests.

You can modify the timeout a couple different ways, there are middlewares, such as [connect-timeout](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout). You can also set timeouts via your env object or directly in your server.js file.